# How to tell a static cell to open specific view in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a Table view controller with two static cells. Each one, when clicked, should open up a  predetermined view. Each cell should act like an element in a tab bar, if that's easier to understand.  I've tried to connect each cell to its view with a push segue, but it looks like when I do so, the storyboard is setting that push for the whole table.

How do I connect each cell to a open unique view?

(I would be willing to implement this with 2 Buttons on a regular view controller, instead of a table as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol in your class, and implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ((indexPath.section == customSection) && (indexPath.row == customRow))
    {
        // Your custom action here
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the "your custom action here", how to I programmatically open the view I want?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what your "predetermined view" is. If you intend to push another view controller you can, for example, call [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];